# How to start Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Hope you are fine. Can you refer me any `how do i` video series for crystal report?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking one of SAP's [e-learning courses](http://www.sap.com/services/education/catalog/elearning/sap-businessobjects.epx).  They seem to be $695 each.